# Same named function but execute based on a condition

Tags: javascript, jquery

Wondering why this is happening

For example, I created an alert function with the same name, then set it a conditional statement, with 2 different conditions which should execute if true or false.

On the desktop, I see `"SEE THIS ALERT"`, which is what I would expect, as the condition is true.

However on mobile, I see "SHOULD NOT SEE THIS ALERT" , which is unexpected seeing how that condition is false.

Why is the same-named function in the "test_two_condition" condition executing on mobile, even though its condition is false, yet on Desktop is performing as you would expect?

```
var test_one_condition=true;
var test_two_condition=false;


if(test_one_condition) {
  function SameName() {
    alert('SEE THIS ALERT');
  }
}


if(test_two_condition) {
  function SameName() {
    alert('SHOULD NOT SEE THIS ALERT');
  }
}

SameName();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because of [scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope). The problem doesn't have anything to do with whether it's desktop or mobile — for example, I just ran the same code in Firefox, Safari, and Chrome on the same computer and got `SHOULD NOT SEE THIS ALERT` on Safari. You have two functions with the same name in the global scope, so which function is actually `SameName` probably depends on the JS engine implementation details.

If you wanted to define these functions in a way that didn't pollute the global (or parent, if this were in another function) scope, you could use const or let bindings, but then you wouldn't be able to call the function, because those use block scope rather than function scope:

```
if (test_one_condition) {
  const SameName = () => {
    alert('SEE THIS ALERT');
  }
}


if (test_two_condition) {
  // or with `let`
  let SameName = () => {
    alert('SHOULD NOT SEE THIS ALERT');
  }
}

SameName();
// SameName is not defined
```

If you wanted to change the result of a function with the same name, you could declare it with a let or var, then assign it in the conditionals:

```
let SameName

if (test_one_condition) {
  SameName = () => {
    alert('SEE THIS ALERT');
  }
}


if (test_two_condition) {
  SameName = () => {
    alert('SHOULD NOT SEE THIS ALERT');
  }
}

SameName();
```

And just in case anyone comes across this question at some point and gets the impression that defining functions based on a condition using names in the global scope would be a good way to do things, deciding what action to take in the function would of course be a better way to go about it:

```
const sameName = (cond) => {
  const msg = cond ? 'SEE THIS ALERT' : 'SHOULD NOT SEE THIS ALERT'
  alert(msg)
}

sameName(someCondition)
```